# Sencha Touch - How to get list itemtpl to display JSON child objects?

Tags: json, list, object, sencha-touch

I am having some problems trying to display child objects using itemtpl property for a list. here is an example of the issue

JSON String:

```
{"messages" : [{"body":{"special":"some special format", "plain":"plain format"}}]
```

Model:

```
Ext.regModel('MyFeed', {
        fields: [
            {name: 'body'}
        ]
    });
```

Store:

```
var FeedStore = new Ext.data.Store({
        model: 'MyFeed',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'data.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'messages'
            }
        }
    });
```

List:

```
var FeedList = new Ext.List({
        itemTpl : '<div>{body}</div>',
        store: FeedStore,
        width: '100%',
        style: 'background-color: #dfe2e3',
     plugins: [{
        ptype: 'pullrefresh'
     }]
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a mapping:

```
Ext.regModel('MyFeed', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'body'},
        {name: 'special', mapping: 'body.special'},
        {name: 'plain', mapping: 'body.plain'}
    ]
});
```

Comment: Thank you!!!!! Was like beating my head around this one, I knew it had to be simple and I kept making it hard.