# Sencha Touch - Aliases for model field names

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, sencha-touch, extjs

I have a bunch of code for viewing data from a Store that I want to use across multiple applications with minimal changes; however, the data is being loaded from a different REST service depending on the application, and the services sometimes have different names for the same field.

Is there any way I can tell the Store, Proxy, Model, Field, or something else to use an "alias" to get around this problem? As in, I want a field named "city", but when the store loads its data, it assigns to "city" the data from the field "pr_city" in the JSON response.

My response looks like this:

```
{
"d" : [
    { pr_city: "Denver", ... },
    { pr_city: "Chicago", ... },
    { pr_city: "Miami", ... }
]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out there is a "mapping" property in the config for field objects.

```
fields = [
    { name: 'city', mapping: 'pr_city' }
]
```

found it in [Sencha Touch - How to get list itemtpl to display JSON child objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6721598/sencha-touch-how-to-get-list-itemtpl-to-display-json-child-objects), credit to Evan Trimboli.